# How to have GRUB on two hard drives and fix giant GRUB partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, dualboot

I have two hard drives - let's call them sda and sdb. sda used to be my main one; it has GRUB and Linux (Kubuntu 20.04) on it.

I had one problem with it: When I installed, I accidentally gave GRUB a humongous partition of 200 GB.

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is orders of magnitude more than what GRUB needs, but I am unsure how to fix it. GParted does not want to shrink the partition.

I figured: *"Let's also install GRUB on sdb. That way, if I have two working GRUBs and I accidentally mess up one of them, I can still boot."*

I installed GRUB on sdb using:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Now I can boot from sdb. But I can no longer boot from sda! My old GRUB is broken and now says this when I try to boot from it:

```
Loading Operating System ...
error: symbol `grub_calloc' not found
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

[image]

This suggests that GRUB is way more brittle than I thought. I did not consciously change anything on sda, but somehow my GRUB there broke. :( Maybe the **grub-install** command I used above didn't do what I thought it did...

Curiously, when I look at sdb in GParted it doesn't say it has GRUB on it...

[image]

Can anyone please advise me? How can I have a GRUB installation on each hard drive that both let me boot my Linux, and without letting GRUB hog more space than it needs?

In case it matters: I believe my firmware uses BIOS rather than EFI. My motherboard is from 2010 or 2011, I think.

Comment: Boot into live USB > delete that grub2 core img drive and create a new one of smaller size > chroot into installed kubuntu > install grub and update configuration ; let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "install grub and update configuration"? Update configuration how?

Comment: to install and update grub configuration in kubuntu : grub-install /dev/sda && update-grub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

1. Boot from sdb. Boot into Linux.
2. In GParted, delete the 200 GB GRUB partition.
3. In GParted, create a 1 GB partition and commit. (Not sure if needed.)
4. In GParted, edit flags of the 1 GB partition and add the GRUB flag. (Not sure if needed.)
5. From a command line, run:

```
    $ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I now have GRUB on both hard drives.

I still don't understand why my first `grub-install` command wrecked one of my GRUBs. That remains a mystery to me...